Dynamically map a discriminated type union to another discriminated type union
Say I have the following type union:
type Shape = Triangle | Rectangle;

interface Triangle {
    type: "triangle";
    base: number;
    height: number;
}

interface Rectangle {
    type: "rectangle";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

How can I dynamically map this discriminated type union to another discriminated type union? For example:
type ShapeMessage =
  | {
      contentType: "application/vnd.shape.triangle";
      content: {
        base: number;
        height: number;
      };
    }
  | {
      contentType: "application/vnd.shape.rectangle";
      content: {
        width: number;
        height: number;
      };
    };


You can achieve this by leveraging generics, keyof type operator, indexed access types, conditional types, mapped types, template literal types and utility types as follows:
First create a discriminated union map:
type DiscriminatedUnionMap<Union extends object, Discriminant extends keyof Union> = {
  [
    DiscriminantType in Union[Discriminant] extends keyof any
      ? Union[Discriminant]
      : never
  ]: Omit<
    Extract<Union, { [_ in Discriminant]: DiscriminantType }>,
    Discriminant
  >;
};

/*
 * Equivalent to:
 *
 * type ShapeMap = {
 *   triangle: {
 *     base: number;
 *     height: number;
 *   };
 *   rectangle: {
 *     width: number;
 *     height: number;
 *   };
 * };
 */
type ShapeMap = DiscriminatedUnionMap<Shape, "type">;

Then re-map the previous map and extract its values as a type union:
/*
 * Equivalent to:
 *
 * type ShapeMessage =
 *   | {
 *       contentType: "application/vnd.shapes.triangle";
 *       content: {
 *         base: number;
 *         height: number;
 *       };
 *     }
 *   | {
 *       contentType: "application/vnd.shapes.rectangle";
 *       content: {
 *         width: number;
 *         height: number;
 *       };
 *     };
 */
type ShapeMessage = {
  [P in keyof ShapeMap]: {
    contentType: `application/vnd.shapes.${P}`;
    content: ShapeMap[P];
  };
}[keyof ShapeMap];

Example usage:
function processShapeMessage(message: ShapeMessage) {
  switch (message.contentType) {
    case "application/vnd.shapes.triangle": {
      const { base, height } = message.content;
      console.log("Triangle base and height are:", base, "and", height, "respectively");
      break;
    }
    case "application/vnd.shapes.rectangle": {
      const { width, height } = message.content;
      console.log("Rectangle width and height are:", width, "and", height, "respectively");
      break;
    }
  }
}

Note: DiscriminatedUnionMap is re-usable across any discriminated unions whose discriminant field isn't nested.
